# How to manage this scenario with SonarLint? Differential analysis for changes of a branch

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarqube-5.4

We are writing software using heavy branching. With Eclipse-Sonar plugin we did analyse our branches before reintegration to the base branch. Here we analysed the new issues for the legacy base branch. The reintegration was only able to start when the branch had no new issues.

While switching to SonarLint we cannot do this type of analysis anymore. We would like to be able to check for new issues compared to the base branch. Is there any possibility using SonarLint to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible yet.

The plan is to support the tracking of resolved issues in future releases: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-72